# Openframeworks : The GLFW library is not initialized

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, openframeworks

I have installed openframeworks and opencv. I am creating application from openframeworks. its compiling fine but if I execute I get the below error.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
[ error ] ofAppGLFWWindow: 65542: GLX: GLX extension not found
[ error ] ofAppGLFWWindow: couldn't init GLFW
[ error ] ofAppGLFWWindow: 65537: The GLFW library is not initialized
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the same binary is working in other computer having openframeworks and opencv.

My computer is having nvidia graphics card .

the executable binary is using the below library related to glx

```
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fab23a0f000)
```

below is display info.

```
lshw -c display

  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK208M [GeForce 920M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
```